# aehair.com is currently unable to handle this request. 500

Tags: php

Last I update the website it is woring but today when I try to visit it, error message display:

> The aehair.com page isn’t working
>
> aehair.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   500

I've check for error logs on cPanel, file manager, `public_html`,

I see error log:

> [27-Mar-2016 16:53:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Can anyone please help me with this?

I do appreciate any help.

Comment: As a general practice, when something was working, but now it is not, it helps to find out all the changes recently made and investigate to see if they caused the problem, even if it seems improbable to be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem loading the `imagick.so` extension.

If you are not using it you could comment it out in the `php.ini` file like this:

change this:

```
extension=imagick.so.
```

to this:

```
;extension=imagick.so.
```

Otherwise you may need to reinstall it because it seems like there is a problem loading the shared object file `libMagickWand.so.2`.

---

#### Locating the `php.ini` file

If you have shell access to the machine (i.e. `ssh`) you can find the `php.ini`  file using the following command:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

which would return something like

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

which indicates the loaded configuration is in `/etc/php.ini`

You could also place a `.php` file on your server with `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in it and then look for the `Loaded Configuration File` section, *but this may not work depending on how messed up your configuration is.*

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for a very quick response.

I would like to try your first suggestion which is to comment on the php.ini file and add the given code on it which is
;extension=imagick.so.

questions:

1. Can I find the php.ini file under /public_html in the file manager on cpanel?
2. If I don't see the php.ini file, can I create one and add the code you mentioned?

Than you.

Comment: No the php.ini file will not be in the public_html folder it is a config file and would usually reside in /etc. If you are using cpanel then i assume you have a hosting provider, you may need to contact them.

Comment: @user3639874 imagick.so is the ImageMagick extension; maybe cpanel has a location to disable ImageMagick. Here is a video that shows [how to modify the `php.ini` file from cpanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuXA-aNxBlE)

Comment: I see, but I don't get response from the hosting support yet until now, I waited for days already. If it's okay with you, can you let me know the exact location of the said php.ini file for the issue?
I mean ca you just tell me where it is located or where can I find it by going to cpanel for example, then file manager or whatsoever?

Comment: If you have shell access to the machine (i.e. `ssh`) you can find it using the command `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"` which would return something like `Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini` which indicates the loaded configuration is in `/etc/php.ini` - you could also place a `.php` file on your server with `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in it and then look for the `Loaded Configuration File` section

Answer (score 0):

Might be the server space issue. We also were facing the same issue. Finally we got to know because of server space. I had faced this issue in magento.